# Missing username on Gerrit with LDAP

Tags: ldap, gerrit

I've been trying to figure this one out for a few days with no luck and finally decided to post question regarding missing user name in Gerrit profile. I've successfully managed to setup git, Gerrit and LDAP individually and authenticate in Gerrit with LDAP. But the problem is missing username which is necessary for ssh connection. Tried couple of variations of Gerrit config but nothing works. Also should mention that ssh connection works when Gerrit uses OpenID.

Gerrit config file:

```
    sslVerify = true
    server = ldap://xxxxxxxx/

    #username = ${username}
    accountBase = ou=People,dc=srees,dc=com
    accountPattern = (&(objectClass=person)(uid=${username}))
    accountSshUserName = ${sAMAccountName.toLowerCase}
    #accountSshUsername = sAMAccountName
    #accountSshUserName = uid
    accountFullName = displayName
    accountEmailAddress = mail

    groupBase = ou=Groups,dc=srees,dc=com
    groupMemberPattern = (&(objectClass=group)(member=${dn}))
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you make it work eventually?

To me it seems weird that you use sslVerify together with ldap:// (not ldaps://) protocol. Also the username option should contain "login" to log on the LDAP server to perform a query.

I didn't have to do anything special to make Gerrit SSH work with AD. It uses the userName attribute.

Answer (score 0):

When using LDAP with gerrit important part is to make sure that the `accountSshUserName` would be populated properly. When ldap is used gerrit does not allow to set it by user manually and it would stay empty, which would cause that the user won't have access via ssh.

if you check in the  `<gerrit-home>/logs/sshd_log` you should probably see something like this:

```
[2019-10-16 11:18:59,129 -0400] 5bc68bb1 lmcdipr - AUTH FAILURE FROM xxx.xxx.xxx.xx user-not-found
```

To make sure that username is populated set properly `accountSshUserName` to for example `cn` or what ever schema you are using.

Example config:

```
  server = ldap://ldap
  username = cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com
  accountBase = dc=example,dc=com
  groupBase = dc=example,dc=com
  accountPattern = (&(objectClass=person)(cn=${username}))
  accountFullName = displayName
  accountEmailAddress = mail
  accountSshUserName = cn
```